# Runtime [Dynamic] Updation of Gmap key for android

Tags: android

We have developed an app with google maps. Ours is a B2B solution and we don't want to bundle our gmap key with the application as we can't meter and bill each customer for their usage. We would like to get the gmap key through configuration from our webserver for each client.

We are looking to provide gmap key dynamically from the server via api fetch to the android application. As far as i have searched it doesn't seem to be possible with google maps key as we need to hardcode it in google_maps_api.xml file. kindly let me know the way for dynamic updation of gmap key at runtime or suggest us an alternative model for our use case.